# Error importing "large" file through MS Access into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, import

I’ve got a problem importing a text file into SQL Server through an Access front-end app.

Background
The application uses Access 2010 as a front end to a SQL Server 2008 back end. My app gets its information by importing data from another, purchased application that does the first chunk of work (payroll). We have to do imports because, although the other app also uses SQL Server, we are not allowed to get data directly from their database.

The payroll app exports data as tab-delimited text files [FYI, I really like this format because – unlike the CSV format -- there is no confusion as to which fields are which] which are then imported into my app with custom code and validations/error reports.

Problem
There are four files that are imported each week; three of them work just fine. The fourth one – the largest, something like 40MB – hangs / winds up throwing a debug error. The other three files are only 2-4MB. I can’t see anything wrong with the code… the size is the only difference I can see.

Any suggestions for: 1) solutions; 2) identifying the cause?

Thanks...jon

Comment: What objects and methods are you using? File System Object TextStream.Readline?

Comment: How are you importing the data into SQL Server?  Via `BULK INSERT`?

Comment: I edited the problem description but no one's reviewed it yet ;-/ Import is done via DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet with custom import spec (all character fields; validation done in a later step).